# Getting HTTP ERROR 500 only on homepage, Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, error, home-page, http-error-500

**Hello, guys!**

I get weird behavior Magento 2.

I get a 500 error only on the home page, and on all other pages everything works correctly.

[image]

How can this be fixed? Please, help)

Comment: please see magento logs under var/log directory& resolve those issues:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved problem!**

It all consisted in the fact that the header was very large, or rather its size is *9.5* kilobytes, and the **nginx** limit was *4* kilobytes

I increased the limit for **nginx**

*The header itself is formed so large due to client settings: for products in the carousel, it was mandatory to display the product id in the carousel in INSPECT, which is displayed on the homepage using the widget*

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the .htaccess file from your Magento root folder and then try to load your website in the browser.

If it doesn't give 500 internal server error after removing the .htaccess file, then there must be some PHP version issue or any server configuration is missing.

Comment: 500 error did not disappear from the homepage, but the rest of the pages that worked well stopped

I can’t understand why only the homepage gives a 500 error, and everything else works fine

Comment: try to find error in log files under var/log directory & resolve those issues

Comment: This is a server error, and Magento errors are written to these files

Answer (score 0):

If using apache for example not having an additional module like mod version will throw 500 error. So you are not reaching magento application. Which means nothing in magento logs.

You will have to try and check server logs too. Exact location will be different depending on your stack.

Comment: Anyway, I don’t understand why the site works well, but the homepage gives a 500 error

Answer (score 0):

go to bootstrap.php which will be in app/bootstrap.php  (nano app/bootstrap.php) and uncomment the #ini_set('display_errors', 1);line in the sense it will be like ini_set('display_errors', 1); it will help you to show error message in front-end and fix the error.Happy coding
fell free to drop any comments